# Google Chrome Setting is not working

Tags: google-chrome

Hi I am having the problem in google chrome browser, nothing is displayed in the tabs (just blank) , having title 'Untitled'. New tab opens but when type url and hit enter nothing happens.
Network is working properly because other browser's are working fine.

I just wanted to reset the default setting ,for that when i try to click on settings, nothing happens, as it is supposed to open a tab with URL='chrome://settings/'. I just wrote this url by myself in the new tab eventhough it doesn't work. then i just uninstalled the chrome and downloaded the new one and set it, but still i am having the same problem 
 Can AnyBody help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**I want to know that any site is opening in chrome or not?**
If not then may be your browser proxy setting is not set to default
Just change the setting to default

Comment: No, no any site is being opened. I can not reach to the point to set the browser proxy setting as default because as i already mentioned that

Comment: i think you could clean the registry of your pc.May be it helps you

Comment: I am scared to do it because it may create some other errors on registry, and i don't know how to do it too.